# How do I control the amount of Toasts that are displayed without them forming a display queue?

Tags: android

I'm developing an Android app that basically is a game. In the main activity there is a button to start playing and other buttons that are also part of the game, but if the user presses any button other than to start, a Toast is displayed asking him to press the start button. The problem is that he can press other buttons several times, flooding the screen of Toasts that repeat the number of times they were requested.

The desirable thing is that there was no queue at all, that is, the Toast would only be displayed if there were no other Toast on display.

P.S. Leave buttons invisible or disable click are not options.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Code?

Comment: You could use a background thread that toggles a boolean value every X seconds. Check the value in order to control whether a Toast can be triggered.

Comment: Use SnackBar instead of Toast

Comment: @ShahidKarimi So far nothing, I have no idea how to do.